# Pandas groupby and transitivity property

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe describing for each transaction (`TX_ID`) which addresses have been used.

For simplicity, the dataframe could look like this:

```
TX_ID Address
1     "address2"
2     "address3"
2     "address1"
1     "address1"
2     "address4"
3     "address50"
```

I wish to identify clusters according to two simple rules:

- All addresses used in a transaction belong to the same cluster `c`
- **Transitivity:** if an address appears in multiple transactions, the transitivity property applies and all addresses in such transactions belong to the same cluster

For instance, according to the previous dataframe I would expect:

```
# CLUSTER1: ['address1', 'address2', 'address3', 'address4']
# CLUSTER2: ['address50']
```

I started by grouping on `TX_ID` to have all addresses used in each transaction:

```
df = df.groupby('tx_id')

TX_ID Address
1     "address1"
1     "address2"
2     "address1"
2     "address3"
2     "address4"
3     "address50"
```

After that I don't know how I could group them according to the transitivity rule without iterating over the groups and doing some checks. Is there a easier way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be seen as a network problem. You can form the links between all TX_IDs through the addresses and then look for disconnected groups.

Once we've formed the clusters, we can map those labels back to the original DataFrame based on the TX_ID an then aggregate to get all of the addresses within those groups.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
df = pd.DataFrame({'TX_ID': [1,2,2,1,2,3], 
                   'Address': ['address2', 'address3', 'address1', 'address1', 
                               'address4', 'address50']})
```

#### Code

```
# This will create all pair-wise combinations of Addresses within TX_ID
def gen_pairs(df, gp_col):
    nwk = df[['TX_ID', gp_col]].merge(df[['TX_ID', gp_col]], on=gp_col).drop(columns=gp_col)
    nwk = nwk.drop_duplicates()
    return nwk

# All pair-wise combinations of Address
dfn = gen_pairs(df, 'Address')

# Create the graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(dfn, source='TX_ID_x', target='TX_ID_y')

# Visualize which TX_IDs are linked. Not necessary, just for illustration
ax,fig = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))
nx.draw(G, node_size=30, with_labels=True, font_size=15, edge_color='#1f77b4')
plt.draw()
```

[image]

```
def connected_component_subgraphs(G):
    for c in nx.connected_components(G):
        yield [x for x in G.subgraph(c)]
        
grps =  [*connected_component_subgraphs(G)]
#[[1, 2], [3]]    

# Uniquely label each gruop
d = dict((k, i) for i in range(len(grps)) for k in grps[i])
#{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1}    

# Bring label back to original DataFrame
df['cluster'] = df['TX_ID'].map(d)
#   TX_ID    Address  cluster
#0      1   address2        0
#1      2   address3        0
#2      2   address1        0
#3      1   address1        0
#4      2   address4        0
#5      3  address50        1
```

#### Output

```
# Aggregate by these clusters
df.groupby('cluster').Address.agg(set)
#cluster
#0    {address2, address1, address4, address3}
#1                                 {address50}
#Name: Address, dtype: object
```